# how to silence gcc warning against c++17 features?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

I self built gcc 7 to try out some new c++17 features.

When I built the code, I saw hundred lines of warnings, saying certain features are available only when -std=c++1z (I have already specified -std=c++1z in the build command line and I tried gnu++1z too)

I want to silence this warning. when using clang 4, there was an option -Wno-c++1z-extensions

but this option is not recognized by gcc.

Comment: Can't you compile with `-std=c++1z`?

Comment: Note that if your code uses c++17 features you would need to use a c++17 compiler. Apparently you do this by specifying `-std=c++1z`. Just to try to silence "warnings" is not the way to go - it's a bad idea to throw a compiler for one language at another language and just telling the compiler to shut up about everything it doesn't understand.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I already specify -std=c++1z, the warning doesn't go away

Comment: @skyking what do you mean? I used gcc7, a c++17 compiler and in the build command line I specified -std=c++1z already? the warning doesn't go away?

Comment: Are compiling manually or with some makefile/cmake/...? Because this kind of thing typically turns out to be that either the compile option didn't actually reach the compiler (CFLAGS vs CXXFLAGS and the like) or that the invoked compiler wasn't the expected one (bad toolchain file, CC vs CXX, configure not being re-run, whatever). Did you try to invoke manually this compiler over a single cpp file with C++17 features and see if it still gives those warnings?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I use cmake. My code builds and runs fine, without any problem. the c++17 feature I'm using is ok too. the only problem is the build time warnings, because there are so many of them, I can't see my actual errors clearly (I'm using tmux). That's why I want to disable them.

Comment: @MatteoItalia your assessment was right. it was because of cmake overriding my -std=c++1z setting

Comment: @BillYan According to you you applied `-std=c++14` which probably makes `gcc` a `c++14` compiler instead. Still it's not advisable to use this setting and just trying to supress the warnings - you should really use the correct language setting instead...

Comment: I told you, it's a classic; in future to debug this kind of problems you can do `make VERBOSE=1`, you'll see all the command lines used to invoke the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

I have root caused the reason for my problem.

It's because I set -std=c++17 with cmake. and I also have included Qt5. Qt5 settings overwrote my -std=c++17. With make VERBOSE=1, I could see both -std=c++17 and -std=c++14.

This confuses the compiler.

the problem is related to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16468

Comment: Had the same problem, just wanted to add that's generally happens when you specify -std flag twice with different values, not just related to QT. I guess it's parsing the lesser of the two value.

Answer (score 2):

gcc 12 supports the option to suppress the warning of the specific c++ version

> `-Wno-c++17-extensions` ( work well both on gcc12 and clang)

ref gcc/clang compiling options:

https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gcc-12.x/html/gcc/gcc.html#Warning-Options

https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/tools/clang/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#diagnostic-flags

but it's better to support c++17 features through flag:

- `-std=c++17`
- `-std=gnu++17`